# change area of product backlog item including children in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

How is it possible to change the area that a product backlog item resides in including it's children? I know that I can open a backlog item and simply change the area, and it will be moved. But any in progress or to do tasks that are linked as children of that backlog item will be lost.

What I want is to be able to change the area as you can change the iteration path by moving it entirely to another area, including its linked childeren items. Otherwise, after a move, I need to alter every single task that is left behind.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the most pretiest way to solve it, but it seems to work. What I now do is expand all items in the general backlog. Then I select all the items and edit them all at once.

This way, I can change the area of the backlog items, and all included tasks that are linked as children. This also means that items that are "done" will be moved to another area.

I don't really understand why this is not made easier, and that other people do not encounter this problem. When working with teams, you can't prevent that backlog items (and linked children) need to be moved between them.

Answer (score 0):

This is no default feature or setting in TFS Sever which could achieve what you need.

You need to do this with help of some 3-party tool such as **[TFS Aggregator (Web Service)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-web-service)**

> *Some uses cases:*
>
> Update the state of a Bug, PBI (or any parent) to "Done" when all
>   children get moved to "Done" or "Removed"
>
> ....

It's also suitable for updating area filed for all children. You need customize  rules through the extension.

More related tutorial for TFS Aggregator, please refer this [link](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/intro/).